# Postgres return count array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with two fields: `provider` and `location` which a json column, from which  I am pulling `cord` object from json.

I would like to aggregate(count) cord by provider.

query:

```
SELECT_provider  ,array_to_json(array_agg(location->'cord'))
FROM charging 
GROUP BY provider 
ORDER BY provider
```

result for my query

```
provider1   [[45, -122],[52, -122.1] [51, -122.1]
provider2   [[45, -122],[53, -122.2]
```

I would like to see

```
provider    #cord
charger1      3
charger2      2
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `array_to_json(array_agg(location->'cord'))` can be simplified to `jsonb_abb(location -> 'cord')`

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data that is stored in that `location` column?

Comment: instead of formating your array to json. You could simply check the array length.
array_length(array_agg(location->'cord'))

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
     Select  provider, 
         strpos(in, ']' , -1) - 
        strpos(in, '], ' ) as op from
        (SELECT provider  
         ,array_to_json(array_agg(location- 
          >'cord')) as in) 
           FROM charging 
          GROUP BY provider)
```

Comment: There is no `instr()` function in Postgres